# Where did the scenery for the Star Wars anti-smoking PSA come from?

Tags: star-wars, behind-the-scenes, advertisements

A saw a link today to the classic *Star Wars* droids’ anti-smoking public service announcement.

It looks like C-3PO and R2-D2 are working in a warehouse or storage area filled with large, probably obsolete power electronics.  However, the many of the devices, lined up in rows, actually resemble Tesla coils or very old-fashioned electrical condensers; this makes me suspect that they may not actually have been real useful electronics but merely science fiction set dressing, probably built for some earlier production.  If this is indeed the case, what show or film were the machines built for?  And if not, where did they get this room full of huge obsolete electrical equiment?

Comment: Some very interesting info here about the [childhood immunisation PSA](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=b8ZD9RcC8P0) that was filmed on the backlot in London; https://melmagazine.com/en-us/story/star-wars-immunization-poster-oral-history

Comment: R2 really did have a smoking habit didn't he? You can see one of his discarded butts here on the ground between him and 3PO - https://archive.org/services/img/01TheStoryOfStarWarsPartI/full/pct:500/0/default.jpg