# What is C-3PO working on in this video?

Tags: star-wars, object-identification

This awesome PSA from the 70’s is super cool to watch. I love the retro-feel of all the electronics in the room and it kinda makes me think of Andor.

It’s driving me crazy but I can’t figure out what C-3PO is working on in the beginning. It’s a strange looking device and makes a bubbling sound. What could it be?

Comment: Semi-dupe of https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/246144/where-did-the-scenery-for-the-star-wars-anti-smoking-psa-come-from

Comment: I'm going to guess *"a sparking piece of futuristic-looking machinery"*

Comment: Looks a little like a WWII analog targeting computer (which were all clockwork, gears, and relays) with the cover off.